# Adding URL parameters based on mobile-detect.js output

Tags: javascript, forms, url, squarespace

I've got a Squarespace form that has hidden fields that are collected and submitted as long as the hidden fields are populated in the URL like squarespace.com/contact-us/?SQF_SOURCE=facebook

I'm trying to collect device and browser with mobile-detect.js (https://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/) but how would I go about adding/appending:

```
?SQF_BROWSER=chrome&SQF_DEVICE=android
```

to the URL so it can get submitted along with the form?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example page on your Squarespace site that contains an example form with hidden fields so that others can verify behavior and test solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend avoiding use of the query parameters, and simply setting the `value` of your hidden fields directly. The following example uses [bowser](https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser) instead of mobile-detect.js, and would be inserted via [code injection](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815908-Using-Code-Injection) in your Squarespace site.

```
<script>
window.Squarespace.onInitialize(Y, function(){
  var dI = document.querySelector("[name='SQF_DEVICE']");
  var bI = document.querySelector("[name='SQF_BROWSER']");
  var script;
  var setInfo = function() {
    dI.value = bowser.osname + " " + bowser.osversion;
    bI.value = bowser.name + " " + bowser.version;
  };
  if (dI && bI) {
    if (!window.bowser) {
      script = document.createElement('script');
      script.onload = setInfo;
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bowser/1.9.3/bowser.js';
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
    else {
      setInfo();
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Keep in mind that [user agent detection has its limits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent). As an alternative, you might consider sending a [custom event in Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) when the form is submitted, then use the aggregated data in Google Analytics to analyze device and browser information.